# Import data from file delimited with various number of spaces

Tags: matlab, file, parsing, import

I am trying to read in [this](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data) data set into a cell array but have two problems

1) the delimiter is spaces that vary on each column

2) 6 of the entries in the 4th column have question marks instead of numbers

What is a good way to read this data into a cell array from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x = importdata('auto-mpg.data'); %// read lines
y = cell(numel(x),9); %// preallocate with 9 cols (acccording to your file)
for n = 1:numel(x)
    y(n,:) = regexp(x{n}, '(\s\s+)|\t', 'split'); %// split each line into 
    %// columns using as separator either more than one space or a tab
    %//(according to your file)
end
```

The result is in the  398x9 cell array of strings `y`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Does importData simply read each line of document and place it as an element of a vertical vector (so a vector of strings)?

Comment: What about spaces inside the quotations for the car names?

Comment: What do you mean? You didn't mention that in the question. Do want to _split_ based on those spaces too? Remove the double quotes? Remove the spaces?

Comment: I mean the 9th column has names that contain spaces and i dont want to turn a name with 2 words into two different columns. Does this preserve the names whole?

Comment: I see, this works, now i simply need to convert the columns 1-8 into ints/floats. Why does the regex not split up the sentences with spaces?

Comment: Because the regexp looks for at least _two_ spaces or a tab as a delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code based on MATLAB Import Tool:

```
% Initialize variables.
filename = '/home/gknor/Pulpit/auto-mpg.data';
delimiter = {'\t',' '};

% Read columns of data as strings:
formatSpec = '%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%[^\n\r]';

% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

% Read columns of data according to format string.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true,  'ReturnOnError', false);

% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

% Convert the contents of columns containing numeric strings to numbers.
% Replace non-numeric strings with NaN.
raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = dataArray{col};
end
numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2));

for col=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    % Converts strings in the input cell array to numbers. Replaced non-numeric
    % strings with NaN.
    rawData = dataArray{col};
    for row=1:size(rawData, 1);
        % Create a regular expression to detect and remove non-numeric prefixes and
        % suffixes.
        regexstr = '(?<prefix>.*?)(?<numbers>([-]*(\d+[\,]*)+[\.]{0,1}\d*[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1})|([-]*(\d+[\,]*)*[\.]{1,1}\d+[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1}))(?<suffix>.*)';
        try
            result = regexp(rawData{row}, regexstr, 'names');
            numbers = result.numbers;

            % Detected commas in non-thousand locations.
            invalidThousandsSeparator = false;
            if any(numbers==',');
                thousandsRegExp = '^\d+?(\,\d{3})*\.{0,1}\d*$';
                if isempty(regexp(thousandsRegExp, ',', 'once'));
                    numbers = NaN;
                    invalidThousandsSeparator = true;
                end
            end
            % Convert numeric strings to numbers.
            if ~invalidThousandsSeparator;
                numbers = textscan(strrep(numbers, ',', ''), '%f');
                numericData(row, col) = numbers{1};
                raw{row, col} = numbers{1};
            end
        catch me
        end
    end
end

% Replace non-numeric cells with NaN
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) && ~islogical(x),raw); % Find non-numeric cells
raw(R) = {NaN}; % Replace non-numeric cells
data = cat(2,raw,dataArray{9});

% Clear temporary variables
clearvars -except data
```

More about Import Tool you can find [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-data-interactively.html).